# Creating a model with multiple target categorical data in Machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the Data which has over 50 coulmns all categorical. My goal is to train a model where i can predict for "Final-Target". But this "Final-Target" has the dependecy on other columns. For example:

Final-Target = y, Target 1 = y1, Target 2 = y2, Target 3 = y3,

Now, if any on these Target 1, 2, 3 has a positive value, the Final-Target will be positive also. If T1 is positive and T2 and T3 are negative, the Final-Target will be positive. I searched the internet and came across " Multi-Target classification ". Where i can train my model on multiple targets, which are all categorical data. Is this the right apporoach to solve ? Can i here use Nueral Network to train a model in which a cell will be activated if any of these sub target is positive than the Final-Targt will also be positive ?

I am new to Machine Learning. Any suggestion on how to approach this problem ? Thanks !

Comment: Are you trying to predict the first three targets or just the final target? If so, then I would recommend passing the first three as features. Another option could be to train three separate models that predict each of the 3 target variables, then create a larger model containing those models which predicts the final target.

Comment: Goal is to predict the final target. But not directly rather than predicting the first three targets and then the basis of these the final target prediction. so, if any of these target is positive, the final target will also be positive.

Comment: Ho will you connect these three models together to get the final model ?

Comment: I will freely admit to never having done this personally, but DataCamp has an Advanced Deep Learning with Keras course that goes into more detail. Of course, it is not a simple answer either because there are many options for model architecture, but one choice could be to create three separate models, the outputs of which become input for a fourth model, along with the original features if so desired.